# Lua replace string with function

Tags: lua

I want to replace matched string with some function.

I've used '%1' to find strings, but I couldn't use the matched strings.

print(text) showed me %1, not matched string.

```
original_text = "Replace ${test01} and ${test02}"

function replace_function(text)
    -- Matched texts are "test01" and "test02"
    -- But 'text' was "%1", not "test01" and "test02"
    local result_text = ""

    if(text == "test01") then
        result_text = "a"
    elseif(text == "test02") then
        result_text = "b"
    end

    return result_text
end

replaced_text = original_text:gsub("${(.-)}", replace_function("%1"))

-- Replace result was "Replace  and"
-- But I want to replace "Replace ${test01} and ${test02}" to "Replace a and b"
print(replaced_text)
```

How can I use matched string in gsub?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `replace_function` gets called before `gsub` can start running. `replace_function` doesn't know what `%1` means, and it doesn't return a string that has any special meaning to `gsub`.

However, the following information from the [`gsub` doc](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub) tells us that you can pass `replace_function` directly to `gsub`:

> If `repl` is a function, then this function is called every time a match occurs, with all captured substrings passed as arguments, in order.

```
original_text:gsub("${(.-)}", replace_function)
```